# Center one tag and position one at bottom in same div

Tags: html, css

My question is simple, I have a `<div>` with two `<p>` tags inside of it, I want one centered vertically in the `<div>` and the other to be at the bottom, is there a simple and clean way to achieve this?

Here is the code: https://jsfiddle.net/xpm7fsoh/

Comment: read carefully the accepted answer, you will find the example you are looking for

Answer (score 0):

```css
.App {
  display: flex;
  text-align: center;
}

.Container {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: red;
  padding: 50px;  
  display: flex;
  height: 50vh;
}

.One {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.Two {
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-end;
}
```

```html
<div class="App">
  <div class="Container">
    <p class="One">Hello</p>
    <p class="Two">World</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hello, did you look at the result of your code? It does not look like it should, neither of the tags are in the center or at the bottom, also they are not horizontally aligned.